# Error while compiling Angular 2 & Firebase Storage

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm currently using Angular 4.x.x (all latest versions) and using AngularFire and Firebase Storage.

Everything was working correctly up to an update made to the Angular CLI/Compiler where now the app was rendered uncompilable.

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
      // Snapshot code here
  }, function (error) {
      // Unsuccessful upload code
  }, function () {
      // Successful upload code here
  });
```

This is where the compiler fails, where I get an error that reads as follows:

### Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Unsubscribe'.

### Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

I'm importing firebase with:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Apparently it is failing on the void function (which hasn't ever failed before)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem thankfully firebase accepts an object as a second param. I changed my code to

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', {next :function (snapshot) {
  // Snapshot code here
}, error: function (error) {
  // Unsuccessful upload code
}, complete: function () {
  // Successful upload code here
}});
```

This seem to work and shut the compiler up.